# DGPS post-processed Kinematic (PPK)

Tags: gps, land-survey, dgps

I did a dGPS survey last summer. Unfortunately, we didn't have a base station. So I did my survey in post-processed Kinematic PPK mode. Because we borrowed the equipment, we don't have access to post-processing software. So here I am with Trimble files (filename.t01) from our survey that need to be post-processed to get accurate positions. Fortunately there are online services that can do the post-processing for you. After converting the files to RINEX format (filename.o) I was able to successfully have them processed by an online service at [Natural resources Canada](https://webapp.geod.nrcan.gc.ca/geod/tools-outils/ppp.php?locale=en).

However, the output is providing me with a track and not with the individual points from the survey. These were marked during the survey and are marked in the RINEX file with

```
          *** Start of Occupation ***
```

Is there any way to efficiently get out the GPS positions for these individual markers?

Comment: How long was the occupation time at each point?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, without the base station is not the best idea but you still can use (Topcon Tools) software,

Download it free and you can use it with all features in demo mode.
Start new job, define it as dgps 
enter your rinex files (.o) and go to process>>compute coordinates then report

[image: Please have a look at the picture attached]